# <!--more--> quicktag breaking FancyBox plugin on my blog's front page

Tags: plugins, read-more, quicktag

I use a plugin on my blog that allows the user to click on an image to enlarge it in a pop-up window. My plugin of choice for this task is the [FancyBox for WordPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/fancybox-for-wordpress/).

Most of the time the plugin works as expected. However, I have discovered that it doesn't function on images found on the front page of my blog if the image is part of a post which contains the `<!--more-->` quicktag.  For posts *without* the `<!--more-->` quicktag the FancyBox functionality is working as expected.

Also, on the corresponding *single-post page* of a post with the `<!--more-->` quick tag, the FancyBox functionality is working as expected. This makes sense since (I believe) the `<!--more-->` quicktag is completely ignored on single-post pages.

I can see from examining the HTML page source that the `class="fancybox"` and `rel="fancybox"` attributes are missing from the images' `<a>` tags on the problem posts. I know that the plugin normally inserts these attributes.  But I don't understand why the attributes are not inserted when the `<!--more-->` quicktag is utilized.

I'm using a custom theme but I have tried a couple of other generic themes and it didn't seem to help.  I have also tried two other FancyBox plugins (Easy FancyBox and Fancybox) and they both exhibited the problem.

My site is http://www.untamedimages.com/blog

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to php and WordPress coding and I don't really know where to start troubleshooting this problem.  I'm happy to provide any additional information if that would help lead to a solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I discovered the source of the trouble I was having and it turns out that it was two misplaced "/" characters in each and every one of my post's html. The extras slashes were being inserted by a 3rd party template. In light of this fact, is there some way to delete my original question? Or, at a minimum, is there some way I can mark it as _closed_?

Answer (score 1):

Your images aren't being encapsulated by the hyperlink markup, so unless you're using additional calls, Fancybox won't know which hyperlinks/images to Fancybox.

You'll either need to fix this in the template loop that your homepage uses, or add some hacky additional call like:

```
jQuery('.post .imgpost').on('click', function($) {
    $.fancybox();
});
```